# How should Ground vias be placed?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, via

I am using vias to filter the input power. The following to pictures show two ways of placing vias. I think both of them are inappropriate since the vias are not "fully" connected with ground through all four "feet".

Is my guess correct? Could I have some comments on placing the vias?

[image: via1]
[image: via2]

Comment: I wouldn't let that second one anywhere near my boards...

Comment: Why do you need thermal relief on a via?

Comment: @VladimirCravero - You generally don't, but if you have extremely short traces between a via and a small SMT part, the solder on one end can reflow before the other, and the part will ["tombstone"](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17710/should-i-worry-about-the-risk-of-tombstoning).

Comment: Trying to use vias to filter input power makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I was using vias to connect gnd with caps. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

First off, the second one looks absolutely horrid.  Don't do that.
Secondly, you should always envelop the actual drill with the trace, whether you need to make the trace large enough to envelop the thermals of the copper via is more a result as to how much current your trace will be carrying.

Comment: For the second point, why is that? The outer plate of a via encloses the drill already.

Answer (score 0):

What sort of filtration are you hoping the vias will deliver to your design?  I've only heard of vias used for microwave filtration.

The second design is not good from a PCB manufacture standpoint because it has sharp inside corners which are likely to be etched out, making the shape of the trace different from what you are expecting.